# Extjs IE8 - Invalid source HTML (Ext.button.Button) (4.2.1)

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8, extjs4.2

I get

SCRIPT601: Invalid source HTML for this operation.

- ext-all-dev.js, line 22833

In IE 8
This is the line:

```
 else {
           el.insertAdjacentHTML(hashVal[0], html);
       }
```

I have created this button:

```
 {
    id: 'deleteGroup',
    cls: 'group-delete-btn',
    focusCls: 'group-delete-btn-over',
    overCls: 'group-delete-btn-over',
    tooltip: 'Delete group',
    xtype: 'button',
    frame: false,
    disabled: true
}
```

The output of the HTML is:

```
<a class="x-btn no-image x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon"
    role="button" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" tabindex="0" href="#authorization/open"
    target="_self" id="button-1039">
    <div id="button-1039-frame1MC" class="x-frame-mc x-btn-mc x-btn-default-toolbar-small-mc x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon-mc"
        role="presentation">
        <span id="button-1039-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap" unselectable="on"><span id="button-1039-btnEl"
            class="x-btn-button"><span id="button-1039-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center"
                unselectable="on"><i>Group </i></span><span role="img" id="button-1039-btnIconEl"
                    class="x-btn-icon-el " unselectable="on" style=""></span></span></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's wrong with this HTML/code?

Comment: Buttons have to be framed in old IE, that's how they get the rounded corners, by injecting a bunch of extra markup. In new browsers, it can just use border radius.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your reply! If I set frame: true in IE8 then I get the same exceptions. :(